# Como executar engine na GPU?

Tags: python, paralelismo

Estou estudando um simulador chamada simian (http://pujyam.github.io/simian/), estou me baseando principalmente nesse artigo aqui: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7408239/

Neste artigo, onde um dos autores é o desenvolvedor da engine, é dito que no loop principal do programa é possível fazer com que ele execute na GPU a partir "escalonador de eventos". Queria uma luz de como resolver isso...

Eis aqui o loop principal da engine:

```
while globalMinLeft < self.endTime:
        epoch = globalMinLeft + self.minDelay

        self.minSent = self.infTime
        while len(self.eventQueue) > 0 and self.eventQueue[0][0] < epoch:
            (time, event) = heapq.heappop(self.eventQueue) #Next event
            self.now = time #Advance time

            #Simulate event
            entity = self.entities[event["rx"]][event["rxId"]]
            service = getattr(entity, event["name"])
            service(event["data"], event["tx"], event["txId"]) #Receive

            numEvents = numEvents + 1

        if self.size > 1:
            globalMinSent = self.MPI.allreduce(self.minSent, self.MPI.MIN) #Synchronize minSent
            while True: #Busy wait for incoming messages; synchronize
                while self.MPI.iprobe(): #Outer repeat loop needed since per standard, MPI_Iprobe can give false negatives!!
                    remoteEvent = self.MPI.recvAnySize()
                    heapq.heappush(self.eventQueue, (remoteEvent["time"], remoteEvent))
                minLeft = self.infTime
                if len(self.eventQueue) > 0: minLeft = self.eventQueue[0][0]
                globalMinLeft = self.MPI.allreduce(minLeft, self.MPI.MIN) #Synchronize minLeft
                if globalMinLeft <= globalMinSent: break #Global queue is not ahead in time to global minsent
        else:
            minLeft = self.infTime
            if len(self.eventQueue) > 0: minLeft = self.eventQueue[0][0]
            globalMinLeft = min(self.minSent, minLeft)

    if self.size > 1:
        self.MPI.barrier()
        totalEvents = self.MPI.allreduce(numEvents, self.MPI.SUM)
    else:
        totalEvents = numEvents

    if self.rank == 0:
        elapsedTime = timeLib.clock() - startTime
        print "SIMULATION COMPLETED IN: " + str(elapsedTime) + " SECONDS"
        print "SIMULATED EVENTS: " + str(totalEvents)
        print "EVENTS PER SECOND: " + str(totalEvents/elapsedTime)
        print "==========================================="
```

Comment: Cnseguir simular - o que quer que você queira - na GPU pode ser complexo, e de fato é o **tema** do segundo paper que você ligou. Responder isso aqui seria uma trabalho equivalente a refazer o paper, e isso sem ter um objetivo bem especificado em vista.